# How to group mesh and vertex group

Tags: objects, armature, vertices

I'm a new comer of the forum.
I have a question regarding mesh and vertex group. I tried to find solution but couldn't.

[What I'd like to do]
When the avatar swing his right hand, the sword is also swung with attaching his right hand.

[Current status]
Sword is not attached right arm. (See the gif)
[image: An swinging sword animation image]

The avatar is generated by [Ready Player Me](https://readyplayer.me/).
Most of elements of the avatar are vertex group.
I can use "join" feature of Blender. But as you know I failed to join the sword mesh and "Right arm" as vertex group. The picture is before joining the mesh and vertex group.

[image]

I guess "join" is not an appropriate option in this case but can't find any best option.

I have basic blender knowledge but not so much knowledge of animation, bone, and vertex group.
Any help or tips are welcome for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you want to do is use a constraint.  If the sword is weighted to a bone, a bone constraint; if it's not, an object constraint.  The most appropriate constraint here would probably be a child-of constraint.  https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/constraints/index.html is the manual on constraints if you've never worked with them before.

Comment: Hello @Nathan 
Thanks for your rapid and kind reply. It's great help for you! I'll try it.

Comment: Additional post. I could realize what I'd like to do by using Constraint. Thanks for your help again!